# Using Linux shell variable as command parameter with spaces

Tags: linux, shell, variables, command, sh

I'm on a synology DS218 and want to create a script to call jdupes which automatically excludes specific directories.
For that I want to call

```
jdupes -rA -X nostr:"somepath/with spaces" -X nostr:"and/some other path" "/mydir"
```

but having the `-X nostr:"somepath/with spaces" -X nostr:"and/some other path"` part saved in a variable, because I call jdupes multiple times in the script and only want one place where I can save my excluded directories.

This is the base of what I tried:

```
excluded_path='-X nostr:`somepath/with spaces`'

jdupes -rAm $excluded_path "/mydir"
```

from that I tried different versions, for example

```
excluded_path="-X nostr:'somepath/with spaces'"
excluded_path="-X nostr:/"somepath/with spaces\""
excluded_path='-X nostr:"somepath/with spaces"'
```

and some more, each time I tried having the $excluded_path with and without ""

Comment: This is what arrays are for, if the shell you are using supports arrays. There is no good solution for shells with no extensions to the POSIX shell standard.

Comment: Consider defining one or more functions that wrap `jdupes` with the appropriate hard-coded arguments, e.g. `jdupes_a () { jdupes -rA -X nostrums:"somepath/with spaces" "$@"; }`, with you can then call as `jdupes_a foo bar` to execute `jdupes -rA -X nostrums:"somepath/with spaces" foo bar`

Comment: @chepner I do think my shell supports arrays, but here I have the same problem:
with `excluded_path[1]="-X nostr:\"path with spaces\""` 
`jdupes -rAm ${excluded_path[@]} "/mydir"` I get the error "could not stat dir path, could not stat dir with ..." or "Invalid extfilter filter name was specified", depending how I set the quotation marks

Comment: You aren't using the array correctly. `args=(-X "nostrums:somepath/with spaces")` Then `jdupes -rA "${args[@]}"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store command-line arguments in an array.

```
excluded_path_args=(-X "nostrum:somepath/with spaces")

jdupes -rA "${excluded_path_args[@]}"
```

The `-X` and its argument `nostrum:somepath/with spaces` are two separate arguments as far as the shell is concerned. (It's `jdupes` that determines what those arguments mean and how to use them.) The array stores each argument as a separate element; the expansion `"${...[@]}"` ensures that each element is treated as a distinct word when building the argument list.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working nicely.
Just to clarify if sb wants to use the exact same command, jdupes uses "nostr:" as input parameter to exclude directories.